# Interpretation of confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I’m studying for an exam and came across a multiple choice question that asked:

> Which of the following about confidence intervals is true?

Apparently, the answer is: For a two sided test, with $H_{0}: \beta_{1} =0$, if $H_{0}$ is rejected at $\alpha=.05,$ then the $95$ percent confidence interval for $\beta_{1}$ would not contain $0.$

This makes sense to me.

However, another option in this question is: Given that $(5.1,9.8)$ is the $95$ percent confidence interval for $\beta_{1},$ the probability that $(5.1,9.8)$ will cover $\beta_{1}$ is $.95.$

Since there is only one answer, the latter is false, but I am having trouble understanding why. It looks perfectly correct to me.

Can anyone provide me some insight?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: 5.1 and 9.8 are constants, as is $\beta_1$.  Either $\beta_1$ is in (5.1,9.8) or it isn’t.   Is there a random variable here that you can make a probabilistic statement about?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Isn’t the definition of a confidence interval $P(a<\theta <b)=.95$ where you are estimating $\theta$?

Comment: a and b are random variables before you run the experiment.  After you’ve run the experiment, all randomness is gone.